# display pointer on hover close icon in search textbox

Tags: css, html

I am using a input type search in my application. I want to display `cursor:pointer` when user mouse hover on x icon in search box , i tried to find out css for this but not find anything releated to this.

[image]

```html
<input type="search">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What browser are you using? Could be a browser-specific feature on text inputs that lets user empty the field by clicking it. I'd search for browser-specific CSS-styles. But it might not be possible to style this.

Comment: @o01 , i am using a chrome browser

Comment: there is not any X in your example code...

Comment: @DanieleFois , when you write something in textbox , you will see x icon at the end of textbox  , like it display into the image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps something like this can work?

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration:hover,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button:hover { 
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```

```html
<input type="search">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `::-webkit-search-cancel-button` selector and set a `cursor: pointer;` on it.

**NOTE**: This only works for chrome and safari. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button) for more info.

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

To place X icon in input u can do this trick:

```css
.input-container {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.x-icon {
  float: right;
}

.x-icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <span class="x-icon">X</span>
  <input style="border: none;">
</div>
```

You can check this solution there: https://codepen.io/Czeran/pen/jGQRLm

Comment: i don't want like this

Answer (score 0):

You can create same functionality with regular `text` input and one `span` element as `x` button if you are not happy with current browser support of `search` input type.

```js
$('.inputField input').on('input', function() {
  var span = $(this).next('span');
  span.toggle($(this).val().length != 0)
})

$('.inputField').on('click', 'span', function() {
  $(this).prev('input').val('')
  $(this).hide()
})
```

```css
.inputField {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inputField input {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.inputField span {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputField">
  <input type="text">
  <span>X</span>
</div>
```